# Typo in static class property declaration react/no-typos

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I created a CRUD app using Redux so, I write  code and when export the component I added this line:

```
AddContact.PropTypes = {
  addContact: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(null, { addContact })(AddContact);
```

But, It's showing this error

```
./src/components/contact/AddContact.js
  Line 461:12:  Typo in static class property declaration  react/no-typos
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Answer (score 51):

should be [p with lower key]

```
AddContact.propTypes
```

Documentation => https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-typos.md

Answer (score 15):

**The issue is in the casing.**

we usually import PropTypes as:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```

We imported as **PropTypes** But while using with a React component.
we use it with smaller case **propTypes** .
example.

```
Blog.propTypes = {
  blog: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`propTypes` is a special property on your `React.Component` (`AddContact` in your case), so it is case sensitive.

Correcting `AddContact.PropTypes` to `AddContact.propTypes` will resolve it.

[Read more from React Documentation.](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)